# Netsuite User Event Script is throwing the Error : "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in Google Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, netsuite, suitescript, stack-size

I try to mandate the Standard Memo Field on the Transactions Record using the Custom Drop Down Field called "Memo Type"  . If the Memo Type value is " Other" the standard memo should be mandated.

I handled this code in User Event Script to throw the "Custom  Error  Messages" for showing the error message while importing the Data's through the CSV Import also.

The Script is working fine by throwing the Custom Error Message, by default Netsuite will throw the server side error message in next page, TO navigate the Form , the Go Back should be pressed .

While pressing the button the Page field data are cleared and Try to add the Values at the Body Field level and the Sublist level.

At this point , **I'm able to re-enter the values at the body fields Level and Unable to enter the Line Items on the Item Sublist**

**while seeing the console log it is showing the error message :"Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" only on the Google Chrome Browser.**

**Code:**

**Suite Script Version: 2.0**

**Type: User Event , Event: Before Submit**

```
  function beforeSubmit(scriptContext) {

      log.debug("Value", " Before Submit Initiated");


      var currentTranRecord = scriptContext.newRecord;

      if (currentTranRecord != null && currentTranRecord != '' && currentTranRecord != undefined) {

          var memoNotesValue = "1";
          var isMemoEmpty = false;
          var memoType = currentTranRecord.getValue('custbody_memo_type');

          log.debug('Value', 'MemoNotes : ' + memoType);

          if (memoType != null && memoType != '' && memoType != undefined) {

              if (memoType == memoNotesValue) {

                  var memo = currentTranRecord.getValue('memo');
                  log.debug('Value', 'Memo : ' + memo);

                  if (memo == null || memo == '') {

                      if (scriptContext.type != scriptContext.UserEventType.DELETE) {

                          var errorObj = error.create({
                              code: 'CANNOT SAVE TRANSACTION RECORD',
                              message: 'Please enter the value for the Memo Field'
                          });

                          throw errorObj.code + '\n\n' + errorObj.message;
                          return false;

                      }
                  } else {
                      return true;
                  }

              }

          }


      }
  }
```

[image: Maximum call stack size exceeded error]

I have studied that the "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" occurs when there is an recursive function. but in my case i'm not using any recursive function.  But in Mozilla Browser the Same code is working correctly.

Help me understand the Cause for the above error. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: if it is browser specific, it should be a client script not, a user event script. you can check client script on current record from customisation > scripting > scripted records

Comment: Hi prasun, I have used both client script and an user event script, in client script is working correct, to check the user event script functionality, i have undeployed the client script and check only with user event script.

Comment: There must be some other client scripts on the record. User event script never runs on your browser. Are you setting scripts on before load ?

Comment: Again to echo prasun, the UserEvent script runs on the NetSuite servers and the Client script runs in the browser.  You should turn off the client side scripts and Workflows that are acting on the client side (browser).  It's impossible to see the userevent script errors in the browser.  Workflows can be set up to run on the client side, check those also.